# AngularJS: How to inject underscore into controller without factory

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, underscore.js

please guide me How can i inject underscore into controller without factory.

with factory my code example is running....here it is.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('_', function() {
  return window._; //Underscore should be loaded on the page
});


myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, _) {

});
```

but without factory when i try to inject underscore in controller then getting error as follows

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   Failed to instantiate module myApp due to: [$injector:nomod] Module
>   'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or
>   forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the
>   dependencies as the second argument.

here is the code without factory injecting underscore into controllers.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp' , ['underscore']);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, _) 
{
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS2',
      'AngularJS1'
    ];

    var x = _.last($scope.awesomeThings, 2);
    _.each(x.reverse(), alert);    
});
```

i am missing something....please tell me what i need to rectify in code. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dependency injection should only be used for angular stuff (services, controllers,...).

Everything that is not related to angular is not supposed to be used with dependency injection.

As far as underscore is loaded before your angular controller, you can use it as it will be added to the window object.

The following will work without any problem :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp' , []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) 
{
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS2',
      'AngularJS1'
    ];

    var x = _.last($scope.awesomeThings, 2);
    _.each(x.reverse(), alert);    
});
```

Comment: see i copy your code but not working here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/3emgttcg/1/

Comment: i used different name for controller here i fixed and code is working without injecting underscore. here is js fiddle version https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/3emgttcg/2/

Answer (score 2):

you can create a separate module for underscore like this

```
var underscore = angular.module('underscore', []);
underscore.factory('_', ['$window', function($window) {
  return $window._; // assumes underscore has already been loaded on the page
}]);
```

Now inject the underscore module to your app module

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp' , ['underscore']);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, _) 
{
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS2',
      'AngularJS1'
    ];

    var x = _.last($scope.awesomeThings, 2);
    _.each(x.reverse(), alert);    
});
```

Comment: i already said i want to inject underscore directly into controller instead of doing it by factory sample. my first sample show how i can inject underscore by factory sample but see my 2nd sample where i try to inject it directly instead of factory.

Comment: @MonojitSarkar This is how DI works. In order to inject something you should define it first. You can't inject it 'directly'.

Comment: is your controller name should be `MainCtrl` or `MyCtrl` ??

Comment: it would be MainCtrl.

Comment: so where did you define the underscore module

Comment: i used different name for controller here i fixed and code is working without injecting underscore. here is js fiddle version https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/3emgttcg/2/

Comment: underscore initially attaches itself to the `window` object so that you can access it globally. but it is not an angular module.That is why we create a separate module with a factory which enables us to access the global underscore functionalities

Comment: I"m getting the following error `Provider '_' must return a value from $get factory method.` Any suggestions?